# Add image to webpage which uses hugo framework

Tags: html, image, hugo, gitlab-pages, hugo-shortcode

I want to post an image onto my blog (yes that simple!)

My website is hosted on GitLab Pages and uses the Hugo framework (v0.23). I forked my webpage from here, https://gitlab.com/pages/hugo (thus my blog folder structure is the same).

My content publishes fine and is stored here:  home/content/post

I created a folder which stores images here: home/content/post/images

When I insert an image into a post the image won't publish. I've tried using the relevant short code in the post (below) with no luck:

1. {{< figure src="image/image_name.png" title="image title" >}}
2. {{< figure src="/image/image_name.png" title="image title" >}}

where:

- the image is stored here: home/content/post/images/image_name.png
- the post is stored here: home/content/post/post_title.md

I suspect the problem is the new images folder I added is somehow not "seen".

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was easily fixed, I was pointing to the wrong pathway. D'oh!

{{< figure src="../image/image_name.png" title="image title" >}}